# Why can't I insert a null value into a notNull column which has a default value?

Tags: postgresql, liquibase

I added a new column in my table using liquibase yml:

```
databaseChangeLog:
  - changeSet:
      id: pay-process-add-column
      author: m.rybalkin
      changes:
        - addColumn:
            tableName: pay_process
            columns:
              - column:
                  name: deferred_pay_notification
                  type: boolean
                  defaultValue: false
                  constraints:
                    nullable: false
```

But when I'm trying to insert a new row with `deferred_pay_notification = null` into the table, I'm getting an error:

```
Caused by: org.postgresql.util.PSQLException: ERROR: null value in column "deferred_pay_notification" violates not-null constraint
```

Can it be fixed?

Comment: Because you're trying to insert a `NULL` value. Don't do that. `NULL` values are not being implicitly coalesced to default values. You will either not want to pass any value for that column, or use the `DEFAULT` keyword, to have it use the default value. Please show us your `INSERT` statement

Comment: Why would you expect to be able to store a NULL value in a not null column?

Comment: Constraints are checked before `DEFAULT` values are applied. And no you can't get around this with a trigger, even a `BEFORE INSERT` one. The ` NOT NULL`  constraint will kick in first. Just passing on a lesson learned.

Comment: And now unlearned. Working on a problem I found out that with at least Postgres 12+ my previous comment is wrong.  You can create a `BEFORE INSERT` trigger/function combination that changes a `NULL` to something else. At some point the validation code changed.